# XDT transformation for JSON in VSTS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there any tool which can transform JSON as well similar to XDT transformations for XML files?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Azure App service deploy task has a variable substitution option supporting json files. You have to provide json file paths and you can use wild cards in the path. You can define the substitute variables and values in the task so that they will be applied in the deployment. However for on-premises IIS deployments there is no task supporting json file variable substitution support as of now. More information on the json variable substitution is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=vsts#json-variable-substitution)

This vsts task source code can be found in [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4) you may inspect the implementation logic there and define your own component to do the substitution of json variables.